# List too long to chmod recursively

Tags: linux, chown

I have tried the following command to chmod many images within a folder...

```
chown -R apache:apache *
```

But i get the follwing error

```
-bash: /usr/bin: Argument list too long
```

I then tried ...

```
ls | xargs chown -R apache:apache *
```

and then get the following message...

```
-bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long
```

Does anyone have any way to do this? I'm stumped :(

Many thanks

William

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Omit the `*` after `xargs chown` because it will try to add the list of all file names twice twice (once from `ls` and then again from `*`).

Try

```
chown -R apache:apache .
```

This changes the current folder (`.`) and everything in it and always works. If you need different permissions for the folder itself, write them down and restore them afterwards using `chown` **without** `-R`.

If you really want to process only the contents of the folder, this will work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "." -print0 | xargs --null chown -R apache:apache
```

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) The correct answer is simply `chown -R apache:apache .`

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name -exec chown -R apache:apache {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the current directory to `chown -R`:

```
chown -R apache:apache .
```

The one corner case where this is incorrect is if you want all files and subdirectories, but not the current directory and the .dotfiles in it, to have the new owner. The rest of this answer explains approaches for that scenario in more detail, but if you don't need that, you can stop reading here.

If you have `root` or equivalent privileges, doing a cleanup back to the original owner without `-R` is probably acceptable; or you can fix the `xargs` to avoid the [pesky, buggy `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and take out the incorrect final `*` argument from the OP's attempt:

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -r0 chmod -R apache:apache
```

Notice the GNU extension to use a null byte as separator. If you don't have `-0` in your `xargs`, maybe revert to `find`, as suggested already in an older answer.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -exec chmod -R apache:apache {} +
```

If your `find` doesn't understand `-exec ... {} +` try `-exec ... {} \;` instead.